# How are if statements with complex conditions treated in C?

Tags: c

Consider the following (somewhat nonsensical) if statement:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

//get i, j from the user, or a file, or something

if(i < 6 && j > 4)
...
else if(j > 6)
...
```

Now, does this compile into something like the following:

- compare i < 6, branch to the `else if` if not
- compare j > 4, branch to the `else if` if not
- `else if`: compare j > 6 (even though this couldn't be true if the second comparison above were false)

or is there some intelligent way of predicting things that simplifies the logic?

Comment: Read about *short circuit evaluation*. And no, there is no way to know how it will compile. The C standard defines how it will *behave*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: short circuit evaluation is only relevant for the posted code if `j` is `volatile` or `_Atomic`.

Comment: @EOF Yeah, but I consider the code only as an example of a "complex condition"

Comment: Interesting.  I've clarified the specific example I meant, `i` and `j` are presented without modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Your first expression is handled like so (the braces make it explicit and easy to read):

```
(i < 6) && (j > 4)
```

But without knowing the order that the operations happen, there is no knowing.

Example, which of the below are equivelant:

```
&x[5]
&(x[5])
(&x)[5]
```

As you have pointed out, C as a language employs [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
This means that once it knows the result of a statement, it will stop processing.

```
x = 3;
if ((x < 6) || do_foo()) {
    /* ... */
}
if ((x < 10) && do_bar()) {
    /* ... */
}
```

In this situation, the `do_foo()` function is *not called*, but the `do_bar()` function is called.

For this reason, it is a bad idea to place any statement which 'may do something' within a conditional - from both a clarity of intent, as well as a purposeful programming point of view (you may be a precedence expert, but the next guy may not be).

Comment: why would `do_bar()` be called here?  The or statement is true in the original if, so the else if is not triggered, not so?

Comment: because the `x < 10` has to be true, but the return value of `do_bar()` also has to be true for the expression to be resolved as true

Comment: Apologies... duff example - see it again.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler can prove the condition of an `if` to always have some value, it may suppress the checking from the generated code. This is usually done if you compile with optimization enabled, where the compiler will try to analyze the code semantically and prove this kind of things.

Using `if(0) { /* ... */ }` is a common idiom used to remove parts of the code, and I know optimizing compilers won't emit any code for it.

That said, I don't know if any compiler will perform this particular optimization you mentioned: skip the `else if` entirely in case j > 4, but I wouldn't be surprised in GCC or Clang did, since they perform pretty aggressive code transformations.

Comment: For further study: this optimization is called [Jump threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_threading)